# How can I set a DateTimePicker value as today's date+1

Tags: c#, .net

How can I set a DateTimePicker value as today's date+1 in code?

Comment: Plus 1 what? day? hour? minute? second?

Comment: if date in 18/02/2011,i want to set the date in datetimepicker as 19/02/2011

Comment: Please mark the correct answer when you get the answer, so that when other users visit this answer then can easily find the answer. Till now you haven't mark any answer as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
```

should do it

Answer (score 5):

Can you pass the binding/context/value as  : `DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

this.dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

Answer (score 1):

set it's selected date to a Datetime.Now.AddDays(1);

Answer (score 0):

you can say like DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)